# How do I make autohotkey click inside the remote desktop session

Tags: automation, autohotkey, remote-desktop

I am trying to click a file base on the coordinates I have provided in my code. The autohotkey can successfully open up the rdp session. However, once the rdp is fully up with its desktop showing, it can't click the file I want it to click. I can't send any commands to the rdp session at all. How do I control the RDP? I follow the coordinates given in Window

```
   Run, mstsc.exe
    WinWait, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
    WinActivate, ahk_exe mstsc.exe
    Send, %ip%
    Send, {TAB}{ENTER}
    if WinExist(ahk_exe CredentialUIBroker.exe){
        Sleep, 1000
        Send, {TAB 2}{ENTER}
        Sleep, 1000
        Send, {TAB 2}{ENTER}
        Sleep, 1000
        Send, %user%
        Send, {TAB}
        SendRaw, %password%
        Send, {TAB 5}{ENTER}
        Sleep, 2000
        Send, {TAB 3}{ENTER}
        WinWait, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
        if WinExist(ahk_class TscShellContainerClass){
            WinMaximize, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass
            
            #SingleInstance force
            #UseHook
            
            Sleep, 3000
            ControlClick, IHWindowClass1, ahk_class TscShellContainerClass,,LEFT,3,x57,y212
            
            
            
        }
        else{
            MsgBox, No
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried launching AutoHotKey with admin rights to see if this enables sending keystrokes and mouse clicks?

Comment: Oh hi I managed to do it by using ControlGet  and ControlFocus =)

Comment: Would you consider answering your own question so this is marked as solved?